# SwiftUI Access TextField Control from within Callback

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
TextField("?", value:$totalDose, formatter: self.decimalFormatter,
    onEditingChanged: { inFocus in
         if !inFocus {
             print(inFocus);
             //Get ACCESS somehow to TextField() from here!
         }
    }, onCommit: {
         print("COMMITED!");
    })
```

I'm looking for a way to **reference the TextField SwiftUI component I'm within from the callback code `onEditingChanged`**.  How do I do this? I have looked at the documentation and does not appear to be any simple way to do this.

I'm doing this so that I can attempt to trigger the textfields commit event and force the decimalFormatter to trigger (which currently does not trigger unless a commit event is fired).

Any help is appreciated!

::EDIT::

So I can into another interesting issue, if you say `self.totaldose=self.totaldose+1` inside the `!inFocus` if statement and tap in the textfield and tap out it will update and run the formatter showing the value increased by 1.  It will keep doing this if you tap in and out. BUT -- the moment you make any change to the value in the field itself the tapping in and out of the control will no longer trigger the event.  It's very bizarre.  Not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior.

::EDIT#2::

Upon further experimentation it appears that once you are editing the field the state of the variable refuses to update the control until a commit event is fired.  I could change other textfields values just fine just not my own once it's in (what I'll call) edit mode.  This means there needs to be a way to dismiss the keyboard properly and send the commit message.

Comment: SwiftUI TextField is not a reference but value, so it is impossible. You have to manipulate with states, not views.

Comment: The issue is it's not possible to manipulate the state to trigger a commit event.  In the old style of doing this with interface builder this was possible by connecting events and actions to controls.  It seems really strange to me that there is no way to do this? Is there a way to set this as a 'value' and then reference this value? Like declare something a 'TextField'.  Use that TextField and then self reference it?